# Join User and LoginHistory in SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce

I am unable to get the user information from LoginHistory object.

I tried using this

```
SELECT User.FirstName FROM LoginHistory
```

but not it says

```
INVALID_FIELD: 
SELECT User.FirstName FROM LoginHistory
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'User' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(LoginHistory.UserId.getDescribe()));` shows "null" as the "relationshipName". Not all relations allow going "up" this way, you can check my answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23507/799 for some examples.

You'll need to make-do with two separate queries. There's equally no way to reverse it because the related list doesn't have name either. This won't work:

```
SELECT FirstName,
    (SELECT Id FROM LoginHistories LIMIT 10)
FROM User
LIMIT 10
```

Maybe there's an idea you can upvote? Maybe you'll have more luck with [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/event_monitoring). Haven't used it personally but my understanding is it can track login, logout, exporting a report... Might be easier to query.

Comment: Thank You. May be I will do with two queries.